# How to re-write oracle SQL statement to comply ansi-98 and convert to DB2 format

Tags: sql, oracle, db2

How can I convert this old oracle SQL statement to DB2 ANSI 98 complied :

```
SELECT 
    O.OBJECT_NAME AS OBJECT_NAME,
    ATT.ATTRIBUTE_NAME AS ATTRIBUTE_NAME, 

    (CASE WHEN R.RULE_NAME = 'LAST_UPDATE' THEN 1 
          WHEN R.RULE_NAME = 'SOURCE_SUPREMACY' THEN 2 
          ELSE 3 END) 

    ID_RULE, 
    RD.SRC_CODE, 
    RD.WEIGTH 
FROM 
    XOBJRULE ORL, 
    XOBJECT O, 
    XATTRIBUTE ATT, 
    XRULE R, 
    XOBJRULEDET RD, 
    CDSOURCEIDENTTP S   
WHERE 
    ORL.ID_OBJECT = O.ID_OBJECT(+) AND 
    ORL.ID_ATTRIBUTE = ATT.ID_ATTRIBUTE(+) AND 
    ORL.ID_RULE = R.ID_RULE AND 
    R.ID_RULE = RD.ID_RULE(+) AND 
    RD.SRC_CODE = S.SOURCE_IDENT_TP_CD(+) AND 
    ORL.PERSON_ORGANIZATION IN (1,3) 
ORDER BY 1,2,5 ASC
```

This SQL statement was extracted from Java debug. How could I just convert it into DB2 format without change notation significantly so as I don't need to review Java code logic?

Comment: If you're capturing SQL in the debugger I'm going to take a guess that you're using some kind of Java persistence framework, such as Hibernate. If that's the case it should handle the change in database transparently. At least that's the rumor... :-)

Answer (score 3):

The query uses Oracle's own outer join syntax `(+)`. For DB2 you'll need to convert all the joins to ANSI SQL 92 explicit join syntax: LEFT OUTER JOIN.

```
...
FROM 
    XOBJRULE ORL
    left outer join XOBJECT O on ORL.ID_OBJECT = O.ID_OBJECT
    left outer join XATTRIBUTE ATT on ORL.ID_ATTRIBUTE = ATT.ID_ATTRIBUTE 
    inner join XRULE R on ORL.ID_RULE = R.ID_RULE 
    left outer join XOBJRULEDET RD on R.ID_RULE = RD.ID_RULE 
    left outer join CDSOURCEIDENTTP S on RD.SRC_CODE = S.SOURCE_IDENT_TP_CD 
WHERE ORL.PERSON_ORGANIZATION IN (1,3)
```

Comment: After made above changes and run app but still get the error: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.LEFT, DRIVER=3.67.27 .

Comment: it works . sorry I forgot to remove "," from "XOBJRULE ORL,"